# How to make Swagger return more information

Tags: swagger, openapi

We have a system with a fairly normal architecture with a front-end, a back-end and a Java service layer in between that transfers requests from the front-end to the back-end and serves responses. The service layer does more than simply passing requests; for example, it sometimes queries multiple services on the back-end and concatenates the data into a single object, to fulfill a single request from the front-end.

The service layer has a basic documentation generated with Swagger, that lists all incoming endpoints and for each, expected parameters and possible JSON response. Each API call is described only by those two sections: *Parameters* and *Response*.

But it doesn't show what goes on between the scene, i.e., what the service layer does to generate the responses, and especially what calls it makes to the back-end to fulfill each request.

What would be the proper way to handle this? What comments / syntax of comments should one add in the code of the service layer, so that it's returned in the Swagger docs (perhaps in its own section)?